# Problem populating Django many to many relationship with list

Tags: python, sql, django, pandas, csv

I am trying to populate my Django SQL db with data from external CSV files but when I run my population file, the parent ManyToManyField model (Film) won't take the query-object which I provide from the child (actor) model because (i think) it is a list. Is it possible to parse in a list to a model with a get_or_create call? If not, how can I work around this problem?

My models.py file looks like this:

```
class Actor(models.Model):
    actor_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

class Film(models.Model):
    film_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    actors = models.ManyToManyField(Actor)
```

And my populate.py file looks like this:

```
import pandas   
df = read_csv('csv_file.csv')

def populate_film():
    for index, row in in df.iterrows():
        film_csv_id = str(row['IMDb ID'])
        film_name = str(row['Film'])
        list_of_actors = row['Actors']

    #The CSV actors column returns a the list of actor_ids which I query against the Actor model
    #I then put these queries into a list for the get_or_create step

    actor_query_list = []
    for actor_csv_id in list_of_actors:
        actor_query = Actor.objects.get(actor_id = actor_csv_id)
        actor_query_list.append(actor_query.id)

    film = Film.objects.get_or_create(film_id = film_csv_id, title = film_name, actors = actor_query_list)
```

The error message i receive reads:

```
Field 'id' expected a number but got [xxxx, xxxx].
```

Thanks!

Comment: My first instinct is that the error is happening past the end of this code, as `get_or_create()` doesn't return a Film object, it returns a 2-tuple, and the error would be from trying to use that later on.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use your field as ID instead of default id field, you should set 'primary_key' attribute to True like this:

```
actor_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)
```

that may solve your problem

Comment: so I added this step and ran the programme which triggered the traceback:  Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use actors.set() instead. So I ran populate_film() without this actors assignment, the model gets filled with every instance of actor from the actor model